# Object overwrites itself when new object is made

Tags: java, graph, graph-theory, edges, kruskals-algorithm

I'm kind of stuck on this program. As of now, I have an Edge object for a graph. This edge object takes a weight and two Vertex objects. I have created a class for the Vertex object, as well as a class for the Edge object:

Vertex:

```
public class Vertex {
private final Key key;
private Vertex predecessor;
private Integer rank;

public Vertex( String value )
{
    this.key            = new Key( value );
    this.predecessor    = null;
    this.rank           = null;
}

/**
 * Return the key of the vertex.
 * @return key of vertex
 */
public Key get_key()
{
    return this.key;
}

/**
 * Set the predecessor of the vertex.
 * @param predecessor parent of the node
 */
public void set_predecessor( Vertex predecessor )
{
    this.predecessor = predecessor;
}

/**
 * Get the predecessor of the vertex.
 * @return vertex object which is the predecessor of the given node
 */
public Vertex get_predecessor()
{
    return this.predecessor;
}

/**
 * Set the rank of the vertex.
 * @param rank integer representing the rank of the vertex
 */
public void set_rank( Integer rank )
{
    this.rank = rank;
}

/**
 * Get the rank of the vertex.
 * @return rank of the vertex
 */
public Integer get_rank()
{
    return this.rank;
}
}
```

Vertex takes a Key object which is just a string and a number.

Edge:

```
public class Edge {
private static int weight;
private static Vertex A;
private static Vertex B;

public Edge( Vertex A, Vertex B, int weight )
{
    Edge.A      = A;
    Edge.B      = B;
    Edge.weight = weight;
}

public int get_weight()
{
    return Edge.weight;
}

public Vertex get_vertex_1()
{
    return Edge.A;
}

public Vertex get_vertex_2()
{
    return Edge.B;
} 
}
```

When I try to declare an Edge object, it works just fine. However, when I create a second one, it "overwrites" the first object.

```
Edge AE = new Edge( new Vertex( "A" ), new Vertex( "E" ), 5 );
```

When I call the methods to print the value of the key (in this case, either A or E), it works just fine. However, when I do this:

```
Edge AE = new Edge( new Vertex( "A" ), new Vertex( "E" ), 5 );
Edge CD = new Edge( new Vertex( "C" ), new Vertex( "D" ), 3 );
```

CD basically overwrites AE. So when I try to get "A" from AE, I get C. When I try to get E, I get D.

I've been stuck on this program for a little while (various different problems in it), but for the life of me, I can't figure out why it's doing this. Can anyone please point out my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because  you define fields as `static`. Static fields belong to class not to objects. In order objects to have their own fields you should not use static keyword. When you create a new Edge object, you overwrite these static fields with new values.

```
private static int weight;
private static Vertex A;
private static Vertex B;
```

Change as below.

```
private int weight;
private Vertex A;
private Vertex B;
```